# create file if does not exits

Tags: batch-file

Hi my script create back up of all file in current directory is as follows:

```
    @echo off
set year= %date:~10,4%
set month = %date:~4,2%
set day = %date:~7,2%
set folder= %date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%

if not exists "%CD%"\%folder%  
(
xcopy "%CD%" "%CD%"\%folder%\ /l /v /s /t /i /y
)
```

But this always gives me
"C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop"\ was unexpected at this time.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction please

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the entire path in double quotes, not just part of it. So instead of

```
"%CD%"\%folder%
```

it should most probably be

```
"%CD%\%folder%"
```

But in any event, I don't think you will be able to copy the contents of a folder to one of its own subfolders.

One other thing is, it should be `IF NOT EXIST …`.

Comment: xcopy -i option creates a directory if it does not exists. I made the changes you suggested  but it says "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\07-12-2011 was unexpected at this time".

Comment: @SREEPRASAD GOVINDANKUTTY: `IF NOT EXISTS …` is wrong, should be `IF NOT EXIST …`.

Answer (score 1):

`if exist` check that a FILE exist. If you want to check for a folder, a little trick is needed using NUL file name that always exist in any folder and with any extension:

```
if not exist "%CD%\%folder%\NUL" ...
```

I hope it helps

Antonio

PS - May I suggest you another method to create your folder name?

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set folder=%%a-%%b-%%c
```